# Looking for sql profiler for sybase since we are using ORM that hides the SQL script executed

Tags: sybase, profiler

I am looking for sql profiler which could be used for sybase database. Since we are using our own custom built ORM, we are unsure about the SQL script generated and executed.
Ideally the profiler should capture the SQL script executed in server at any instant of time for an account.

Any links or references are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use [Embarcadero DB profiler](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/DBOptimizer/en/Sybase#Profiler) or [ORMProfiler](http://www.ormprofiler.com/defaultgeneric.aspx).  If you are looking for something free of cost, try using [MDA tables](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc00497_1500/html/aserbsua/CHDDAJHA.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I also got a solution for `sybase` DB profiling tool [iWatch](http://www.exact-solutions.com/products/iwatch).

This tool is found to have lots of advantages :

1. Client-Server Architecture design 
2. Real time statistics of DB rather than scrolling logs.
3. Supports many DBs along with sybase like MSSQL Server, DB2, Informix etc.

Answer (score 0):

Adding one more tool named ASEMon. This is freeware and lightweight.